# cant import my own object in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

My project has an api.java and a main.java
The main.java uses the api.java

```
 api api = new api();
```

But intellij cant find the api.java. They are in the same folder. When i compile it with javac it does work.

Comment: please provide the package name and class definitions of the involved clases

Comment: And check the classpath setting in the IntelliJ project.

Comment: Also please note that it's customary in Java to use capital names for classes/files - Api.java and Main.java. Remember, Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly mark content roots in IntelliJ:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html

And make sure you correctly configure your JDK, so you can use javac:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html